# regional vs multi-regional buckets

Tags: google-cloud-storage

In the project I see multi regional buckets created by someone by mistake and it is been used for the data pipelines. It should have been regional buckets. What is the recommended way to change this to regional buckets?

Answer (score 2):

You can try following command

```
gsutil defstorageclass set regional gs://[BUCKET_NAME]
```

Reference: [changing default storage class](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/changing-default-storage-class)